# Reindex - 401 Authorization Required - nginx

Tags: error, reindex, nginx

I have set up a local version of our Magento 2 store on my local machine running on Valet+ with Docker serving Elastic Search.

Everything is working great, except I am running into a few errors when i try to reindex. All indexes work as expected apart from 2:

- Catalog Search index
- Search Spell-Correction index

```
...
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:21
Catalog Search index process unknown error:
<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.19.10</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I have cleared caches, set permissions and recompiled, all with no effect. I have search as many forums as i can to find an answer with no luck.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Error will be logged in exception file under var/log. You can share error details here.